# What Can I Do When My App Is Rejected Due to Inconsistent App Signatures?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I have integrated the HMS Core SDK for a game, and recently, and submitted a game update for review in AppGallery, but it is rejected because the app signature differs from that of my released game. Does anybody know the reason?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746)

Answer (score 3):

1.Check whether the current app version is the same as the previous version.

View the fingerprint certificate in the project.

a. Open the CLI and run the keytool -list –v –keystore [file path] command.

b. Enter the keystore password.

c. View the current signing certificate fingerprint.

[image]

View the APK signature.

a.  Run `keytool -printcert -jarfile xxx.apk` (APK file path).

b.  The following information is displayed.
[image]

c.   You can view the SHA-256 certificate fingerprint of the current APK. Check whether this value of the two app versions is consistent.

Then check whether the two fingerprints are consistent with that in your project.

2. If the certificate fingerprints are inconsistent, this can be caused by two different reasons. The first one is that the two APKs have been packaged using different signature files. If they are inconsistent, you should first check whether the .jks or keystore files used for app signing in the project are consistent. Or, you can check whether you have used keystore files from different environments or platforms.
   Example:
   [image]

The .jks or keystore files used for the **debug** and **release** environments are different. You need to ensure that each .jks or keystore file matches the environment. For example, **you cannot configure the .jks or keystore file in debug to the release environment**.

3. If the .jks or keystore files are consistent, you need to check whether an automatic process has been used for packaging and signing. If so, check whether DEX file encryption has been used, which can lead to inconsistent signatures.